# How to use selecttoken of newtonsoft liabrary where key is fully qualified url

Tags: json, .net-core, json.net

I am working on selecting token from JSON. Sample code is below.

```
string json = @"
{
  ""client_id"": ""26075235"",
  ""client_version"": ""1.0.0"",
  ""event"": ""app.uninstall"",
  ""timestamp"": 1478741247,
  ""https://something.com/something/url"": {
    ""id"": ""62581379"",
    ""site_id"": ""837771289247593785"",
    ""platform_app_id"": ""26075235""
  },
   ""nonURLuser"": {
    ""id"": ""62581379"",
    ""site_id"": ""837771289247593785"",
    ""platform_app_id"": ""26075235""
  }
}";

JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);

Console.WriteLine("nonURLuser User ID: " + jo.SelectToken("nonURLuser.id"));

Console.WriteLine("Dot based URL User ID: " + jo.SelectToken("https://something.com/something/url.id"));
```

But the second print is giving blank output.  How can I select this token?

fiddle url :- https://dotnetfiddle.net/RzFyOg

Answer (score 0):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/kkfTVl

found answer. Please dont bother.

```
Console.WriteLine("Dot based URL User ID: " + jo.SelectToken("['https://something.com/something/url'].id"));
```